# Remote debugging an ASP MVC web application on Azure don't work because firewall

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, azure, web-applications

I've made an ASP MVC web application and build and test the application on localhost. On localhost I've no exception, no bug in my code.

Now I've publicized that application on Azure but here I've an exception. I don't know where exactly the exception is thrown. Can I debug the Azure site for find and solve the exception?

**Update 1:** I've tried remote debugging but I've got this error:

[image]

On the <kbd>Help</kbd> button I've not much information about the error.

**Update 2:** I've created my application by clicking the <kbd>Add</kbd> button by app services.

[image]

Thanks in advance.